# modalpopupextender validation is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to fire some validation on the ModalPopUpExtender.But even if there are validation errors in the ModalPopUpExtender,click on the ok button is doing the postback.

How i can stop the submit button from doing the postback if there are validation errors on the ModalPopUpExtender.

Comment: Try to use client validation (jquery validation).

Comment: Post your validation function here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write `return false;` at the end of your function.

suppose you have a function

```
  function validate()
  {
     //your statements
     return false;//write this to stop postback.
  }
```

### Edit:-

Also put return before your function call at button client click. as

```
OnClientClick="return validate()"
```

Comment: yes i'm returning false from the validation function.On debugging also it is working fine but after complete execution of the function there happens a postback.

Comment: add you function in your question only then it would be helpful.

Comment: why don't you put your function in your question.

Comment: put the function body and calling as well.

Comment: I got the expected result by making the CausesValidation property of the button to be set as 'True'.
as per the MSDN document,by default this property is 'True' for the Button,but it was not working as expected.So i have to make it forcefully CausesValidation="True";